# How to persist the state of a Redux reducer in the browser

Tags: javascript, redux, local-storage

In a Redux app the user can define a "reducer" for taking in a `state` object and an `action` object and returning the updated state. When the state corresponds to UI elements that configure how the app works, it's useful to persist them between page reloads. How can this be done?

```
const initialUiConfigState = {"a": "1", "b": "2"};

// Performs the action onto the state and returns the updated state.
export function uiConfigReducer(state=initialUiConfigState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case ACTION1:
      return {
        ...state,
        b: "3",
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The state reported by the reducer can be stored in the browser's local storage. It can be done manually in the reducer or by wrapping the reducer into another one that can do this.

The wrapper reducer can be for example https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#quickstart

Manually, it can be done like this:

```
// Deserialises a value from the local storage.
// Returns null when the value is missing or the deserialisation fails.
export const loadState = (name) => {
  try {
    const serialState = localStorage.getItem(name);
    return JSON.parse(serialState);
  } catch (err) {
    return null;
  }
};

// Serializes a value into the local storage.
// Can fail silently.
export const saveState = (name, state) => {
  try {
    const serialState = JSON.stringify(state);
    localStorage.setItem(name, serialState);
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

const uiConfigStateLocalStorageKey = "xxx-v1";
const initialUiConfigState = {"a": "1", "b": "2"};

// Performs the action onto the state and returns the updated state.
export function uiConfigReducer(state, action) {
  if (state === undefined) {
    state = loadState(uiConfigStateLocalStorageKey);
    if (state === null) {
      state = initialUiConfigState;
    } else {
      console.log("Restoring state:", state);
    }
  }

  let changedState = null;
  switch(action.type) {
    case ACTION1:
      changedState = {
        ...state,
        b: "3",
      };
      break;
  }

  if (changedState === null) {
    // Return the previous or the loaded or the initial state.
    return state;
  } else {
    console.log("Saving state:", JSON.stringify(changedState));
    saveState(uiConfigStateLocalStorageKey, changedState);
    return changedState;
  }
}
```